# Node http-request module returns 503s from google query

Tags: node.js, https, akamai

I have an http-request that returns 503 when i call google.com similarly it returns 400 when i query localhost(127.0.01) I've set up a python listener on post 80 and 443 but the script never makes the connection just returns status code.

Additionally, i have tried changing the user-agent header.

It seems the httprequest() method is not reaching working? Any help is appreciated.

```
    const options = {}
    options.method = "GET"
    options.headers = { "Content-Type": "text/plain", "Accept": "*/*", "User-Agent" : "curl/8.1.2"}
    
    //options.body = request.bodytext
    //createResponse(status, headers, body, [deny_reason])

    return httpRequest('https://127.0.0.1', options).then(response => {  
      return createResponse(
        response.status, {Location: [redirectDomain]},
          response.host);
          }
        );
};
```

Comment: I found the issue -> 

"To use sub-requests you need an associated delivery product. Hostnames can only be requested directly when served through the Akamai network. If you don't have an associated delivery product sub-requests will fail with a 400 HTTP response code."